# What does "tangle off something" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/45581933).

> The Portuguese forward, making his Champions League debut for Juve, appeared to grab Valencia defender Jeison Murillo's hair as they **tangled** **off** the ball midway through the first half and referee Felix Brych consulted his assistant behind the goal before showing the five-time Champions League winner a straight red card.

What confuses me there the most is the use of the preposition *off* there.

Comment: In speech "off the ball" would be a discernible phrase.  It would be overkill, but the text could be punctuated *...as they tangled, off the ball, midway through...*   Do you understand what **straight** means there?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/straight_red_card "A red card, signifying a player's instant dismissal from the game for a single major foul or misconduct, distinct from and graver than a second yellow card, which a player may receive for several minor fouls." for those wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tangled* means scuffled or fought.

*Off the ball* means away from the ball.

So these players had a fight, but not near where the ball was being played.